# Java 8 Streams for List iteration

Tags: java, list, java-8, iteration

I have a `HashMap` that contains `List<Dto>` and `List<List<String>>`:

```
Map<List<Dto>, List<List<String>>> mapData = new HashMap();
```

and an `Arraylist<Dto>`.

I want to iterate over this map, get the keys-key1, key2 etc and get the value out of it and set it to the Dto object and thereafter add it to a List. So i am able to successfully iterate using foreach and get it added to lists but not able to get it correctly done using Java 8. So i need some help on that. Here is the sample code

```
List<DTO> dtoList = new ArrayList();

DTO dto = new DTO();

mapData.entrySet().stream().filter(e->{
    if(e.getKey().equals("key1")){  
        dto.setKey1(e.getValue())
    }
    if(e.getKey().equals("key2")){  
        dto.setKey2(e.getValue())
    }
});
```

Here `e.getValue()` is from    `List<List<String>>()`
  so first thing is I need to iterate over it to set the value.
And second is I need to add dto to a Arraylist dtoList. So how to achieve this.

Basic Snippet that i tried without adding to a HashMap   where List has keys, multiList has values and Dto list is where finally i add into

```
for(List<Dto> dtoList: column) {
  if ("Key1".equalsIgnoreCase(column.getName())) {
    index = dtoList.indexOf(column);
  }
  }
for(List<String> listoflists: multiList) {
if(listoflists.contains(index)) {
for(String s: listoflists) {
dto.setKey1(s);
}
dtoList.add(dto);
}            
}
```

Comment: You say that you have a `Map<List<Dto>, List<List<String>>>`, but in your code you compare the keys of that Map to `String`s. Please edit your question to reflect the actual situation.

Comment: Can you show a bit more what you achieve to do in your foreach ?

Comment: Yes i am iterating over a map where keys belong to List<Dto>, so i am comparing it to a string

Comment: You need to provide more details about your `DTO` object and what are you trying to put in it from your `List<List<String>>`... it is not clear.

Comment: Why are you doint that in `filter` ?

Comment: Dto is a POJO class and has    String key1,         String key2.

Comment: Could you show us the code where you successfully iterate over it using foreach? Your current example code is hard ti interpret.

Comment: @Renukahr1084 I downvoted, the whole code snippet makes no sense to me. `e.getKey().equals("key1")` never becomes `true` since you are comparting a `List<Dto>` and a `String`. If `key1` is a `String`, why are you setting a `List<List<String>>` value to it?

Comment: I second @AndrewTobilko, I don't understand the question. It's not clear for us now, so it will be even less clear for future visitors. Why are you comparing a `List<Dto>` with a String? Why do you have a `List<Dto>` as the key of a map in the first place? Does `Dto` implement `hashCode` and `equals` *consistently*? Are you aware of the consequences of dealing with lists as the keys of a map? What are the values? Do they relate to the keys somehow? Please clarify all this, post an example that compiles and shows a simplified version of your problem, and I'll happily retract my downvote.

Comment: Basic Snippet that i tried without adding to a HashMap  where List<Dto> has keys, multiList has values and Dto list is where finally i add into 
      for(List<Dto> dtoList: column) {
          if ("Key1".equalsIgnoreCase(column.getName())) {
      index = dtoList.indexOf(column);
       }
               }
       for(List<String> listoflists: multiList) {
             if(listoflists.contains(index)) {
          for(String s: listoflists) {
      dto.setKey1(s);
         }
        dtoList.add(dto);
     }   
      }

Comment: Don't post code in the comment section, update your question instead

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

> Stream operations are divided into intermediate and terminal operations, and are combined to form stream pipelines. A stream pipeline consists of a source (such as a Collection, an array, a generator function, or an I/O channel); followed by zero or more intermediate operations such as Stream.filter or Stream.map; and a terminal operation such as Stream.forEach or Stream.reduce.

So in your snippet above, `filter` isn't really doing anything. To trigger it, you'd add a `collect` operation at the end. Notice that the filter lambda function needs to return a boolean for your code to compile in the first place.

```java
    mapData.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> {
        // do something here

        return true;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course you don't need to abuse intermediate operations - or generate a bunch of new objects - for straightforward tasks, something like this should suffice:

```java
    mapData.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
        // do something
    });
```